# Python Django cities-light signals

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django and I don't understand where to put the signal to filter the countries to import  data in django-citites-light.

The doc can be found here:
http://django-cities-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database.html#module-cities_light.signals

But I haven't found a way so the import filters the data using my signal.

Thank you

Comment: You put this either inside your `signals.py` or `models.py` or in the file it makes the most sense.